# How to get indented JSON output in asp.net MVC 5 to view in browser?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

This is only for debugging purpose. Only returning JSON, outputs unreadable JSON string on webpage. Is there any quick solution to view formatted json on webpage?

Looking for a C# function that will take json object and return formatted output as string from my action method.

Comment: Assign it to a javascipt variable and use the developer tools to view it

Answer (score 2):

Just change JSON global settings in your Global.asax file.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};
```

It should produce indented JSON for all your Web API endpoints.

Then you can inspect resulting JSON directly in browser or using some HTTP traffic capturing tool like Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

Use the JavaScript `JSON.Stringify()` function. Example:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/yourController/yourAction",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( data ) {
    alert(JSON.Stringify(data));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. A c# based solution would be nice and quick.

Comment: The JSON object that you get on your view from your action is a JavaScript object. You cannot access it using c#. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. This is only for debugging. I would probably change the return type of my action method later. I don't want to write any javascript code for it.

Comment: @RacilHilan Well, I deleted my comments because this discussion does not give any extra value to the answer and essentially we were fighting about terminology. Still, I would suggest to change you wording regarding JSON not being accessible from C# code. While you cannot access JSON **object**, you definitely can affect its textual representation and respectively how it will be parsed in JavaScript. From current answer one can get impression that it is not possible.